# Квота на дисковое пространство - администрирование по группам

Tags: windows, администрирование

Почему в типах объектов для квот на диск только пользователи.  Как туда, в квотирование, в объекты, добавить и группы домена?

Answer (score 1):

А с чего вообще взяли что есть такая возможность в Windows?В *nix системах есть такая возможность, в а винде нет.

Прочитайте бегло вот эту [страницу](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=8&topic=15162), может инфа от туда поможет реализовать что задумали.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, следует попробовать настройку квот через групповую политику?

**UPD**

Конфигурация компьютера -> Административные шаблоны -> Система ...

... -> Дисковые квоты

... -> Групповая политика -> Обработка политики дисковой квоты

А еще есть консоль управления файловым сервером... ПОМОЩЬ вам в помощь

Comment: Полазил по веткам GPEDIT'а, ни чего явно связанного с квотами на сетевые ресурсы не нашёл.